# Splitting domain to 2 servers with a 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns

Be forewarned, most of the terms used here were not in my vocabulary 24 hours ago.

Our company wants to remove wordpress from our current windows OS server at providers 1 and move it to a new server at provider 2. Godaddy handles our DNS. Our SEO consultant wants it to have the same url it currently has.

I would like to make a DNS entry on godaddy so that our current server and our new server can use the same URL (ie sellstuff.com). But I only want the DNS to direct traffic to our current server. The goal here is to have the new server using the same URL as the old server so nothing needs to be masked once traffic is redirected with a 301 rule in the htaccess file.

I would then like to edit the htaccess file on our current server to redirect to the new servers IP address when someone goes to sellstuff.com/blog.

Does this make since and is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can redirect the trafic of `sellstuff.com/blog` to a new server. You need to:

1. Have a static IP address or a domain pointing to the new blog server (to be able to access it).
2. Configure your new blog server to have all internal links pointing to `sellstuff.com/blog/*`.
3. Redirect all trafic to `sellstuff.com/blog/*` from the current server to the new server with `.htaccess` rules:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)$ your_new_server_ip_or_url_with_http$1 [P]
   ```

   so it will be something like this:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)$ http://10.0.0.1$1 [P]
   ```

Comment: Thank you!. What type of DNS record should I use when adding the IP of the new server? I don't want to actually redirect traffic to that server through the DNS. I just want it to be able to pull the same domain.

Comment: You just need a public static IP address for the new server. Do not add it to the DNS. The `.htaccess` will access transparently to the new server (via the proxy module `proxy_mod`).

Comment: How do I make the new server use the same url/domain as the current server without adding it to the dns?

Comment: DNS only give a "traduction" from URL (`example.com`) to the IP (`192.168.0.1`). So you will provide only the IP in the `.htaccess`.